# Как сделать вертикальное выравнивание дивов наподобие ячеек в строке таблицы?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать вертикальное выравнивание дивов относительно родителя так же как горизонтальное у ячеек в строке таблицы у блока с изменяющейся высотой на 100% его высоты, причем высота задана не явно.

Например, можно сделать вот так:

```css
.block{
  position:relative;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.item{
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.item_1{background:#1e2faa}
.item_2{background:#aa5e67}
.item_3{background:#32aa4a}
.item_4{background:#a4aa53}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="item item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item item_4">4</div>
</div>
```

И внутренние ячейки будут растягиваться относительно ширины, равными размерами. Хочу сделать такое-же, но вертикально. Чтобы блок тянулся относительно родительского дива, который будет тянуться в зависимости от контента. Причем контент, может быть меньше блоков, а блоков может быть разное количество. То есть абсолютное позиционирование отпадает, так как блоки будут вылетать за границы. Структура должна быть такая:

```css
.parent{
  background:#aaa;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  display:table;
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.item{
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.item_1{background:#1e2faa}
.item_2{background:#aa5e67}
.item_3{background:#32aa4a}
.item_4{background:#a4aa53}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
<div class="item item_1">1</div>
<div class="item item_2">2</div>
<div class="item item_3">3</div>
<div class="item item_4">4</div>
  </div>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</div>
```

То есть нужно сделать вот так, блок адаптивный:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Флексы годятся?

```css
.parent {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item_1{background:#1e2faa}
.item_2{background:#aa5e67}
.item_3{background:#32aa4a}
.item_4{background:#a4aa53}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item item_1">1</div>
    <div class="item item_2">2</div>
    <div class="item item_3">3</div>
    <div class="item item_4">4</div>
  </div>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

А вот и вариант с гридом:

```css
.parent {
  background: #aaa;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item, .right {
  padding: 5px;
}

.right {
  grid-row: span 4;
}

.item_1{background:#1e2faa}
.item_2{background:#aa5e67}
.item_3{background:#32aa4a}
.item_4{background:#a4aa53}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item item_4">4</div>
  <div class="right">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а нельзя ли такие длинные строки кода разбивать на куски поменьше (если их невозможно просто сократить)? а то вот [эта страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) становится нечитабельной. спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это было бы нелогично, поскольку для ответа эта строка не представляет важности. Очевидно, что разработчики SO накосячили со страницей - лучше было бы на мете спросить. Тем не менее, вот стили, которые исправляют ту страницу: `.default-view-post-table { width: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 185px; } .default-view-post-table > tbody, .default-view-post-table > tbody > tr { display: contents; } .default-view-post-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child { width: unset !important; overflow: auto; }` Можно вместо `1fr` написать `500px`, как задумано разработчиками.

Comment: [спросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371596/298597). надеюсь, с предложенным css-ом ничего там не напутал.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, плюсанул. Но по идее им там вообще надо таблицу на нормальный лейаут переделывать. Вообще, я имел в виду нашё мету, чтобы можно было стили ответом запостить на случай, если кому-то ещё понадобится, а то в комментах же никто не найдёт.